# How to add Kendo image editor text insertion tool

Tags: javascript, r, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, edit

I want to use `Kendo Image Editor` in my project, but **I want to add text to the images** I will put as custom. I looked in the documentation but couldn't find information about it. **How to add text to Kendo Image Editor?**